# extracting values from typed xml in sql server

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, data-extraction

I have typed xml as one of the columns in my table (sql server 2008). I need to extract one specific value from this typed xml field. I checked across multiple sites, but only ways to extract a field from untyped xml alone is given. Help me in getting this gone.

Comment: Are you able to give some example code, e.g. some xml, simple column/table structure?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge you query typed XML the same way as you do untyped XML. Do you get an error or something?

Answer (score 0):

If by typed you mean xml that has namespaces, try something like:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http: //www.MySampleCompany.com' AS MY)
SELECT
   chapters.node.value('../@title', 'nvarchar(50)') AS bookTitle
FROM @data.nodes('//MY:chapter') AS chapters(node)
```

Vote down or comment if I misunderstand your question.